# dynamic row height

Tags: iphone, uitableview

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
//cell.backgroundView = [[[CustomCell alloc] init] autorelease];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[CustomCell alloc] init] autorelease];

// At end of function, right before return cell:
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


// Configure the cell.
UILabel *myLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-30, 3, 300, 22)];
UILabel *myLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 22, 310, 200)];
UILabel *myLabel3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 300, 20)];

Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    myLabel1.text=aBook.title;
    myLabel2.text=aBook.description;
    myLabel3.text=aBook.pubDate;

    NSString *desc = aBook.description;
    if ([desc isEqualToString:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"nullll lll ");
    }


//myLabel2.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;              
myLabel2.numberOfLines=5;   
myLabel2.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
myLabel2.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
myLabel2.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
myLabel3.numberOfLines=1;
myLabel1.numberOfLines=1;
myLabel1.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
myLabel1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
myLabel1.shadowColor=[UIColor redColor];
myLabel1.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel3];
```

hi guys! i have this following code, i want to display this from xml file. now its working but static row height. 
if the xml file dont have data then it leaves it as blank. so i want to change row height according to the data i provide using the mylabel1,2,3.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question aright (and apologies if I don't), then:

1. Implement the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method in your tableView delegate - get it to calculate and return a suitable height for the row;
2. Configure the sizes (or just remove from the superview) the UILabelViews you are adding to the contentView. You do this in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
3. Make sure you reload the table or, better, reload only the rows that have changed - this forces the tableView to fetch the height again

Here's an example of a tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath method for a single section table that dynamically resizes the height of the cell row depending on how much text there is in the paragraph being displayed.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath;
{   
    CGFloat rowHeight = [self rowHeight:[[self paragraphs] objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
    return (rowHeight + EI_CELL_MARGIN);
}
```

And then a fragment from the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.

```
NSString* cellText = [[self paragraphs] objectAtIndex: [indexPath row];
[[cell paragraphController] setText: cellText];
[[cell paragraphController] adjustFrameToTextSize];
```

(As it goes in this code I've subclassed UITableViewCell for convenience. The 'paragraphController' is just a ViewController with a view added to the cell's content view. The adjustFrameToTextSize method resets the view frame depending on the size of the content to display.)

Answer (score 2):

As specified in the [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, you want to implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method in your delegate. In that method, you're given the `indexPath`, so you can repeat the line

```
 Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Once you have the book, you can check its properties (looks like `title`, `description`, and `pubDate`), then instead of adding them to the cell (which you do later), you return a calculated cell height based on the property values.

Comment: pls let u tel some basic level. i m newbie to iphone, i didnot get u sorry

Answer (score 1):

Hi There  is one sollution try the method of NSString . write this is Height for cell

```
NSString *text1 = [arrOutline1 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH , 20000.0f);
CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGFloat YPostion =MAX(size3.height, 44.0f);

cellHeight = cellHeight + YPostion + 20;;

return cellHeight ;
```